# White screen on startup on Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've made my first Android app from scratch and I'm fairly new at Android development.

I've made a small app that basically fires off an API call and then displays data on the screen depending on the result from the call.

Problem is, when the app loads it has a white screen for about 3 seconds. I originally thought this was the API call causing the issue but commented that out and still have the same issue.

Have tried a few things but no luck yet. You can see my activity (and rest of my code) here on Github https://github.com/JamieFarrelly/Luas-Strike-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jamiefarrelly/luasstriketracker/MainActivity.java

Comment: Please make your StackOverflow questions self-contained. In other words, show your code here.

Comment: Sorry. On my mobile right now so thought github would be the best.

Comment: Alright, well, it should be mentioned that onStart happens before onCreate, and it doesn't appear in that link that you've commented an API call, so seeing a blank screen makes sense unless you have any static content on that screen

Comment: Yeah I didn't commit commenting it out.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are using in [MainActivity:71](https://github.com/JamieFarrelly/Luas-Strike-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jamiefarrelly/luasstriketracker/MainActivity.java#L71):

`apiResponse = new HttpUtils().execute().get();`

Your `HttpUtils` class extends `AsyncTask` so the `get()` method returns the result on the caller thread, in this case, the main/ui thread. If you don't want to block the main thread you have to use `execute()` only and to move your logic after getting the response to [HttpUtils:onPostExecute()](https://github.com/JamieFarrelly/Luas-Strike-Tracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jamiefarrelly/luasstriketracker/HttpUtils.java#L48)

Comment: Hmm. See I only uses get() to get the response of the api call. I'll have to think more about this. Edit - after reading this again I think you're right, I'll try it later. Thanks.

Comment: It's a tiny bit faster but now the api response isn't always populated so it's showing that something went wrong instead. Hmm

Comment: @user3119841 That happens because you didn't move right your logic in onPostExecute()

Comment: Could be right. I moved setting the apiResponse to there pretty much.